# Executing Thread by run method and Start method

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to execute Thread into the Both method using thread.Run and as well as thread.start

Here the case 
Main Class

```
Thread thread = new GetTimeZones();
ByImletingInterface thread21 = new ByImletingInterface();
thread21.getMailStarttime(5);

ByImletingInterface thread2 = new ByImletingInterface();
thread2.getMailStarttime(10);

thread.start();
new Thread(thread21).start();
new Thread(thread2).start();
```

Thread 1

```
public class ByImletingInterface implements Runnable {
    private int starttime;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Thread.sleep(starttime * 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Checking Mail");
    }

}
```

and Other therad

```
public class GetTimeZones extends Thread {

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Locale locale;
        DateFormat timeforMatter;
        DateFormat dateforMatter;
        String timeoutput = null;
        String dateoutput = null;

        try {
            java.util.Date date;

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                date = new Date();
                locale = new Locale("en");

                timeforMatter = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT,
                        locale);
                dateforMatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT,
                        locale);

                //System.out.println(timeforMatter);
                timeoutput = timeforMatter.format(date);
                dateoutput = dateforMatter.format(date);

                System.out.println(timeoutput);
                System.out.println(dateoutput);
                System.out.println();


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.run();
    }
}
```

how ever for describing my prob both class is not needed but still m giving it.

when i use therad.start into main class like i did. Its sententiously executing three of threads.

But when i use theread.run one by one thred is exected. means its synchronize. Why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the `run()` method, you are running it on the current thread, so of course it will run one by one, as there is only one thread (each `run()` method will be executed after the previous one is done).

Only when you call `start()` a new thread is created and the `run()` method is executed in that new thread.

Comment: cit: Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases, Puzzle 76 - https://books.google.com.au/books?id=RM9sLE0ntQ0C&pg=RA1-PT216&lpg=RA1-PT216&dq=java+puzzlers+ping+pong&source=bl&ots=1_hAzcjdfU&sig=HanjnxNBTUQ4byPczjnGixttfZU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=stNZVZLuAqG8mQWAj4HgBg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=java%20puzzlers%20ping%20pong&f=false

Comment: @Krishna Yes (assuming you call the `run()` method from the main thread and not from the run method of some other thread...).

Comment: Your answer is true, but it reflects the language that the noob used in the question.  That language feeds his confusion.  When code calls `foo.run()`, it does not _run_ anything:  It's just a method call like any other.  `thread.start()` also is just a method call.  What does `start()` do?  If you follow it into the native implementation, you find that it creates a new thread that will call `...run()`.  What does `run()` do?  (This is where you wake the noob up and say, "You _wrote_ it!  You tell _me_ what it does.")